# Need a flexable reporting tool

Tags: reporting-services

We are tasked with creating a reporting frameworks that does the following.

Clients can create list reports from the web.
Schedule reports to run at a given time.
Developers should be able to use a full report layout tool to design reports without code
Reports respect data filters.

Can I get these options with any packages that or out there? If so which ones?

Comment: "Developers can use a full reporting tool design reports without code Reports respect data filters." - can you rephrase this sentence, please? I can't parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting services is a fantastic tool and framework, and if your runing SQL Standard or Enterprise you obviously can't beat the price.

SSRS can do all of the things your requesting except I am a bit confused on your sentence

> Developers should be able to use a full report layout tool to design reports without code Reports respect data filters

With SSRS you can filter at the data level or the report level, but if my concern for your reqs would be that your clients will be accessing it via web.  If your on the same network SSRS is very simple and everything is great.  But if your clients are going to be accessing your reports thru a browser and are not inside your network, you must create a custom authentication which will can be very tricky if your wanting to secure your reports or give certain users access to certain reports.  Which will require a decent amount of code.

If this didnt answer your question please feel free to rephrase.